# Using str_getcsv in php

Tags: php, csv

Whenever I try to use str_getcsv in my php code it returns no arrays and opens to the page with a 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
$csvfile = "master1.csv";
$input = file_get_contents($csvfile);
echo $input;
array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]] )
```

Comment: You really should learn to differentiate between the __syntax depiction__ in the PHP docs, and the way to use it in your code.... `array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]] )` tells you that the `str_getcsv()` function takes one mandatory argument of type string, and 3 optional arguments of type string, and returns an array..... you call it using `$myArray = str_getcsv($inputString);` (assuming defaults for the optional arguments, and that your input data is $inputString

Comment: And if your $input is more than one line, then you need to loop over each row, because str_getcsv() works on individual lines, not the whole file..... though easier to use fgetcsv() as you're reading a local file anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string` word is telling you that the next variable you enter has to be a string, and the `[` and `]` is telling you that the argument is optional.

This should work;

```
$csvfile = "master1.csv";
$input = file_get_contents($csvfile);
echo $input;
$myArray = str_getcsv($input);
```

To get the result:

```
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just starting and this helped me greatly.